# SwiftUI adding custom UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboardsegue, swiftui

I'm trying to create `SwiftUI` custom segue animation, like this

[image]

I try to chain the animation to `Destination` but no use, it just animates inside the contents of `Destination` after presentation animation finish.

```
struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                List {
                    NavigationButton(destination: withAnimation{
                        Destination()
                        }.frame(width: 300, height: 300)
                         .animation(.basic())) {
                            CellView()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

    }
}

struct CellView : View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Cell")
        }
    }
}

struct Destination : View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("GFD")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you might want to have a look at this https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/204/

Answer (score 1):

you can try with removing the animation

Comment: you can also follow the animations steps mentioned in apple developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/204   as Mikale requested.. me too faced the same issue and shortout by modifying /removing the animation